# Calling the burn function

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I am using the openzeppelin library and importing the `StandardBurnableToken.sol` logic into `MyContract.sol`

here is a code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";
import "/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardBurnableToken.sol";

 contract MyToken is StandardToken {
  string public name = 'Membership Token';
  string public symbol = 'MTKO';
  uint8 public decimal = 18;
  uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 1000000;

 constructor() public {
  totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
 }
}
```

Do I need to add another function in `MyToken.sol` to be able to call the `burnFrom()` function? or is that once the logic is in the ABI it can send tokens to 0x0 addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StandardBurnableToken.sol` already contains references to `StandardToken.sol` and `BurnableToken.sol`, so all you need to do is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardBurnableToken.sol";

contract MyToken is StandardBurnableToken {
     ...
}
```

By doing this, your contract will automatically obtain the `burnFrom()` function, as well as anything from `StandardToken`. You will not need to write any code for this, as it is [already included](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardBurnableToken.sol).

Comment: Awesome thank you. Then once the contract is deployed how do I send an amount to a dead wallet(0x0) or actually burn a set value?

Comment: You need to call the `burnFrom()` function. Possibly through Web3.js or some other API.

Comment: I did find that the MEW wallet has a built function to call the burn()
https://medium.com/@hodl50/how-to-burn-tokens-with-mew-bbf279a09798
However there is nothing in the RPC docs or Web3 calls that invoke burnFrom() function

Comment: You need to call a custom contract method: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12

Comment: This is probably not the right place to have this discussion. Calling custom contracts functions using Web3.js is a pretty well documented thing. It is basically what every website that interacts with smart contracts does. I recommend you do a bit of research, and if all else fails, open a new question.